# Fourier Series - Double Check Work

Tags: signal, signal-processing, dsp, fourier

I was solving this Fourier series problem from my book, but was not able to find a solution to it to double-check my work.

This is the problem:

[image]

My work:

\$T=4+2=6 sec\$

\$C_{n}=(\frac{1}{T})(\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}}f_{(t)}e^{-jnωt}dt)\$

\$C_{n}=(\frac{1}{T})(\int_{-2}^{-1}4e^{-jωnt}dt+\int_{-1}^{1}2e^{-jωnt}dt+\int_{1}^{2}4e^{-jωnt}dt)\$

\$C_{n}=(\frac{1}{T})(\frac{1}{-jnω})(4e^{-jnw(-1)}-4e^{-jnw(-2)}+2e^{-jnw(1)}-2e^{-jnw(-1)}+4e^{-jnw(2)}-4e^{-jnw(1)}\$)

\$C_{n}=(j\frac{1}{2\pi n})(2e^\frac{j\pi n}{3}-2e^\frac{-j\pi n}{3}+4e^\frac{-j2\pi n}{3}-4e^\frac{j2\pi n}{3})\$

\$C_{n}=(j\frac{1}{2\pi n})(2cos(\frac{\pi n}{3}-2cos(\frac{-\pi n}{3}+4cos(\frac{2\pi n}{3})-4cos(2\frac{\pi n}{3})+j(2sin(\frac{\pi n}{3})-2sin(\frac{-\pi n}{3})+4sin(\frac{-2\pi n}{3})-4sin(\frac{2\pi n}{3})))\$

\$C_{n}=(j\frac{1}{2\pi n})(j(4sin(\frac{\pi n}{3})-8sin(\frac{2\pi n}{3}))\$

\$\boxed{C_{n}=\frac{2}{\pi n}(-2sin(\frac{2\pi n}{3})+sin(\frac{\pi n}{3}))}\$

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Were you able to figure out the mistake now?

Comment: Sorry, I corrected my work above, accidentally put -2 instead of -4 when writing it down. I get something very similar to what you have, except where you have 4e^(2j*pi*n/3), I get -4e^(2j*pi*n/3). Here is my work for comparison: https://ibb.co/48QX637

Comment: @Damianpd...I guess it was typo on my side too. Yours is correct.

Comment: Thank you for double-checking my work, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> \$C_{n}=(j\frac{1}{2\pi n})(2e^\frac{j\pi n}{3}-2e^\frac{-j\pi
> n}{3}+4e^\frac{-j\pi n}{3}-2e^\frac{j\pi n}{3})\$

The above intermediate expression looks wrong to me as I obtained as:

$$C_{n}=(j\frac{1}{2\pi n})(2e^\frac{j\pi n}{3}-2e^\frac{-j\pi n}{3}+4e^\frac{-2j\pi n}{3}-4e^\frac{2j\pi n}{3})$$

**UPDATE:**

Your simplification and answer are correct now.